# Jenkins/Groovy Dynamic Choice Parameter Return Specific Pattern

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins job with a Dynamic Choice Parameter. The goal is for this parameter to get a list of the available branches in a git repo, then return only the ones that I want to build the list choices. I want to the list of choices to include: dev, qa, & anything that starts with "7.". For example, it would return 7.23, 7.33 etc. 
This is what I have now:

```
def list = []
def process = "/var/lib/jenkins/GIT/get_branches.sh".execute()
int ii = 0
process.text.eachLine {
  if (it == "dev") {
    list[ii] = it; ii++
  }
    if (it == "qa") {
    list[ii] = it; ii++
  }
    if (it ==~ /7.*/ ) {
    list[ii] = it; ii++
  }
}
list
```

dev and qa are working, but I can't get the pattern matching for "7.*" to work correctly.

Comment: What is your exact problem, do you not get any results for `7` or to many? Please provide the output of `process.text` and `list` and what is missing or to much in it.

Comment: Currently, the last if statement breaks the script and the dropdown in jenkins is blank. So `list` is empty & process.text is a long list of git branches. I found a solution that I'll add as an answer, but optimizations are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a compact solution

```
def list = []
"""foo
bar
700
7.31
7.32
7.33
dev
qa""".eachLine {
  switch (it) {
    case "dev":
    case "qa":
    case ~/7\.\d+/:
      list << it
  }
}
println list
```

Outputs: `[7.31, 7.32, 7.33, dev, qa]`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the following, but I'm open to suggestions on how to do this better:

```
def list = []
def process = "/var/lib/jenkins/GIT/get_branches.sh".execute()
int ii = 0
process.text.eachLine {
  if (it == "dev") {
    list[ii] = it; ii++
  }
    if (it == "qa") {
    list[ii] = it; ii++
  }

    def m = it =~ '^7.*' 
    if (m) {
    list[ii] = it; ii++
  }
}
list
```

This results in the following jenkins dropdown (which is what I was looking for):

```
7.31
7.32
7.33
dev
qa
```